# C++ Class Methods: Calling Method from another Method skips chunks of code

Tags: c++, oop

In trying to practice OOP in C++ (having experience in Java OOP), I am trying to create a little program that keeps track of patients and treat them based off of a queue.

From my PatientManager class, I am implementing 4 methods. A start() method to start the program, a newPatient() method, nextPatient() method and waitingList() method. I have start() running while(true) and it can call any of the other 3 methods based on user input.

I have start() and newPatient() prepared and in testing it, I cant seem to get newPatient() to be properly called. The debugger makes it seem as if start jumps to newPatient and then skips everything that is in the method EXCEPT for the cin.clear() and cin.ignore() and then returns to start() to ask for another user input. I cannot figure out what is wrong.

```
    class PatientManager {
    private:
    //Make a priority queue object
    priority_queue<Patient> list;
    int order = 1;

    public:
    PatientManager() {
        this->list = list;
    }

    void newPatient() {
        string name;
        int emergency;
        bool done = false;

        cout << "Enter patient's name: ";
        cin >> name;
        cout << endl << "Enter emergency [1 (low) to 5(life-and-death)]: ";
        

        while (!done) {
            try {
                cin >> emergency;
                while(emergency >5 || emergency <=0) {
                    cin.clear();
                    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
                    cout << "(x) Wrong choice. Try again: " << endl;
                    cin >> emergency;
                }
                if (cin.fail()) {
                    throw (emergency);
                }
                order++;
                //list.add the patient
                list.push(Patient(name,emergency,order));
                done = true;
            } catch (string e) {
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
                cout << "(x) Wrong choice. Try again: " << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    void nextPatient() {

    }

    void waitingList() {

    }

    void start() {
        cout << "-------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "       (1) New Patient\n";
        cout << "       (2) Next Patient\n";
        cout << "       (3) Waiting List\n";
        cout << "       (4) Exit\n";
        cout << "-------------------------" << endl;

        while (true) {
            int item = 0;
            try {
                cout << "Choose an item from the menu: ";
                cin >> item;
                //Not sure if this is needed
                // if (item < 1 || item > 4);
                //     throw -1;
                if (cin.fail()) {
                    throw exception();
                }

            } catch (exception e) {
                cout << "(x) Wrong choice." <<endl;
                item = 0;
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
            }

            if(item == 1) {
                this->newPatient();
            } else if(item == 2) {
                this->nextPatient();
            } else if(item == 3) {
                this->waitingList();
            } else if(item == 4) {
                cout << "Program terminated. Goodbye!\n";
                exit(0);
            } else if (item < 0|| item >4){
                cout << "(x) Wrong choice." <<endl;
                item = 0;
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I create and call PatientManager.start() from my main class and have a separate Patient class as well.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: FYI, you can get rid of the `this->` syntax by using a coding scheme where methods have a different naming convention than parameters.  You may also get rid of the `this->` syntax by using initializer lists.

Comment: what are you doing in the constructor

Comment: When processing selections from menus, I highly recommend using the `switch` statement rather than an if-else-if` ladder.

Comment: @rioV8 I am just trying to initialize the list to the PatientManager object when it is called. I know this is how it was done in java OOP but am still learning with C++. Do I not need to have this->list = list;?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thank you for the input Thomas, I will keep that in mind!

Comment: What is the `list` on the right side of that assignment meant to refer to? The constructor has  zero parameters defined, let alone any parameters named `list`.

Comment: FYI, since your constructor has no parameters, it simplifies to `this->list = this->list;` which can be simplified to the empty constructor.

Comment: read up on C++ object construction